# meaning and location of string inside Magento's Mage:getSingleton

Tags: magento, singleton

Here is a string I see a lot of similar in Magento:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
```

However, I'm trying to find out where that class is located, and what the meaning of the string is specifically.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1/ Model

You have to know that `Mage::getSingleton()` is going to send you a singleton (which is a common development design pattern). For magento, only Models can be instantiated as a Singleton

Snippet from `app/Mage.php` where you can see that Magento is actually using getModel behind the scene, and also register it to have a single instance of this model if you call it twice via getSingleton (the purpose of the singleton pattern itself, as you may know)

```
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

### 2/ Handle

Magento is going to map its components to classes via what we call handles. Those are defined in the config.xml of the modules.

Snippet from `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml` stripped from a lot of xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Checkout>
            <version>1.6.0.0</version>
        </Mage_Checkout>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <checkout>
                <class>Mage_Checkout_Model</class>
            </checkout>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

This snippet instruct to magento to add at its **global** configuration, for all the **models** it knows a new set of model that could be referenced through the **handle checkout** which maps to the classes beginning with **Mage_Checkout_Model**.

### 3/ The right file or class

Magento does inherit from Zend Framework mapping of Class_To_File_Path

> Class names may only contain alphanumeric characters. Numbers are permitted in class names but are discouraged in most cases. Underscores are only permitted in place of the path separator; the filename "Zend/Db/Table.php" must map to the class name "Zend_Db_Table".

Source : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

That means that the type of construction like **type_onepage** would map to a file having in its path **Type/Onepage.php** and its class name **Type_Onepage**

### 4/ One handle to rule them all

(I had to place that pun somehow, sorry.)

Now you have the handle to you model which map to `Mage_Checkout_Model` and your class which is `Type_Onepage` Magento can assemble those two in a class being `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` and to a file being `Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php`. So this whole handle (**checkout/type_onepage**) is constructed from two part, the first one before the slash is the handle to a model (in this case, but could also be to an helper or a block... controller are a little different) and the second one, after the slash being the path to the file from the folder / class prefix defined by the handle.

### 5/ And you thought that was all ?

To be completely extensive in this explanation you also have to know that modules are defined via an xml which stands on `app/etc/modules`.
Since you are asking for a core module, the file to look at is `Mage_All.xml` which I, once again stripped of a lot of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales/>
                <Mage_CatalogInventory/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

For other module the recommended way to do it is by having a file `app/code/Mage_Checkout.xml` where the name of the file is the name of the handle beside the `<modules>` node in the xml. But for the core, since there is a lot of module they grouped a lot of them in `Mage_All.xml`.

In this file you can see that it has fairly the same start as the `config.xml` of our module we saw earlier, so Magento would be able to match the fact that this `config.xml` belongs to this module defined in this `Mage_All.xml` file.
Then you also see the **codePool** of that module. In this case, **core**, the stock modules of Magento. But you could also have there **community** or **local**.

For now on, Magento can really map to the file correctly.
You file is in 
`app/code/` -- **fixed**, all the code is there.
`core/` -- the **codePool** of your module
`Mage/Checkout/Model/` -- the handle mapped to the right class defined in **config.xml** and then translated to a path based on Zend Framework convention
`Type/Onepage.php` -- The file mapped from `type_onepage`, following once again Type/Onepage convention.

## All in one :

```
echo get_class(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage'));
// will output Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage
// which is located at app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
```