# From where, data comes to block in magento?

Tags: magento, model, block

In base\default\template\customer/account/navigation.phtml the code is

```
<div class="block block-account">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('My Account'); ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content">
    <ul>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 1; ?>
        <?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
            <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

it display the following list :

[image: account information]

i know the block, but i want to know how the block receive this data and from where.if any link between block and model if its  how. any one explain this overall flow.

Comment: No model data is being passed to the Navigation block. Most of the functions are inherited from template block and the abstract class the template extends.

Answer (score 0):

They actually come from a class, which is something you can find back thanks to the block type.

Making a search on my Magento with the template (view) you state here `customer/account/navigation.phtml` will help you find the layout related to it.

And then you can find the block type.

So in `customer.xml`, you can find :

```
<block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
```

And this block type `customer/account_navigation` is actually the class `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` that you can find in the file `src/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Navigation.php`

To find back this class, there is a quite complicated game of xml handles and path to file mechanism that I already explained multiple time already, if you are curious about it : [meaning and location of string inside Magento's Mage:getSingleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604931/meaning-and-location-of-string-inside-magentos-magegetsingleton/30606461#30606461) and [Magento: call a custom block in CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582169/magento-call-a-custom-block-in-cms/30584096#30584096)

The links there, as it looks that is what you are after, are, as you can see, a property of the class itself, that got filled in via :

```
public function addLink($name, $path, $label, $urlParams=array())
{
    $this->_links[$name] = new Varien_Object(array(
        'name' => $name,
        'path' => $path,
        'label' => $label,
        'url' => $this->getUrl($path, $urlParams),
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

And you can also see on some layout that they actually call this method to add links to that block, e.g. in `review.xml`

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
</reference>
```

You can also see that it is the same block because the **name** in the reference node here is the same as the name defined for this block as reproduced here above : `customer_account_navigation`.

Comment: exactly correct brother. 

But i have a confusion from beginning that is, from the above template, we can see this line 

" <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?> ". 

We know the getLinks() method is define in the "Navigation.php" file. 

The code is :
 
public function getLinks()
    {
        return $this->_links;
    }


but here i want to know about this line
 
"return $this->_links;"

here i returns what? and what this "$this->_links" refers or where it's come from

Comment: thanks brother. and i want an answer for an another question. the question link is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293507/how-add-a-customer-reorders-as-a-link-on-toplinks). Sorrry to ask this here, because i dont know how to share this question with you.

Comment: @Naga, you can't share question here, Stack Overflow is not a forum, and please stop calling people "brother" :|